# Can I make list items tabable without assigning `tabindex` to each one?

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, tabindex

I have a list of items that are (a) editable (b) moveable up / down with ctrl + shift + ArrowUp / ArrowDown. I need to be able to focus on individual `<li>` using tab or arrows.

Is there a way to make a list tabable without assigning `tabindex` to each item?

I wish to avoid having to change the `tabindex` value each time I reorder list.

Comment: "*I wish to avoid having to change the tabindex value each time I reorder list.*" not sure why you want to avoid what should be a line of code `document.querySelectorAll(".myListItem").forEach((el, i) => el.tabIndex = i + offset)` (you probably want to start from 1 or something).

Comment: You could set them all to the same value then they'll just go in the order in the DOM, here's an example with all set to 0 then moving one of them (also shows example without tabindex): https://jsfiddle.net/ce9jdfto/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex : *tabindex="0" means that the element should be focusable in sequential keyboard navigation, after any positive tabindex values*